# Low energy strong coupling asymptotic

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, beyond-the-standard-model, strong-force

The low-energy behavior ($Q^2<\text{1GeV}^2$) of the strong interaction coupling constant [predicted by LFHQCD](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ppnp.2016.04.003), $\alpha_S = \pi \exp(-Q^2/4\kappa^2) $, where $\kappa=M_\rho/\sqrt{2}$, is in excellent agreement with experimental data. I'm wondering if the same asymptotic behavior is predicted by any other methods?